# Multiple .env.development configs in Vue/Webpack

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I feel this should not be a hard thing to do, but I can't get it to run.

I want to have two different configs for my local Vue.js project (using vue-cli 3).

- the first having VUE_APP_API_URL on my localhost,
- the other connecting to a development/staging server

So, I want to have `.env.development-1` and `.env-development-2` or something like that; just a way to quickly switch between two otherwise identical configuration files.

I've read about build modes etc, but those articles all seem to target "building". I just want to run local devserver with a different config.

How would I solve this?

Comment: It depends on how you're building your Vue app. If its something using `vue-cli` take a look at https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes .

Comment: i've read that one, but it answers none of my questions. that is what i meant by "everything seems to BUILD something, but i just want to run my dev server with a different config". as i understand it, i can build with different modes, but can i also run the dev server with a different mode? i don't see where this is mentioned

Comment: Before your app is run (by `npm run dev` or `serve`), it is first build (by webpack) so those ENV variables will be injected into your code. This is exactly what you need...

Comment: you guys are right... it totally works :D thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments under my original post, i found out that the solution is, in fact, really easy:

i just made an `.env.staging` with the `VUE_APP_API_URL` pointing to the staging server, everything else being the same

then

```
"scripts": {
    "serve:local": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "serve:staging": "vue-cli-service serve --mode staging",
}
```

and it works.

first had to wrap my head around the concept.
thanks!